# Get friends checkin at a particular location using FBL or graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I want to pull all my freinds checkin at a given location or in a radius of 5000m. 
I am able to pull this data using the checkin Id but not sure how to do it for a location or in  radius of 5000m- I have tried the below query, can someone please help

```
SELECT author_uid FROM checkin WHERE checkin_id ='823627496738' AND author_uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM       friend WHERE uid1 = me()) OR tagged_uids IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use coords column in checkin table.

```
SELECT coords,author_uid,author FROM checkin WHERE coords.latitude < '15.479513888889' AND coords.latitude < '20.479513888889' AND coords.longitude > '70.891111111111' AND coords.longitude < '80.891111111111' AND author_uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) OR tagged_uids IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())
```

you can use something like the above. Here you have to set the latitude and longitude range..
I do not know how to calculate the latitude and longitude within certain radius...
But this might help you